# Не происходит запись данных в сессию

Tags: php

На сайте есть галочка(запомнить меня), всё работает. Но теперь не заносятся данные в неё

```
          if ( $_POST['remember'] == '')
      {
        session_name("user");
      } else {
        session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
        session_name("user");
      }
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
```

Comment: А что такое $user?

Comment: переменная хранящая почту и тп

Comment: Может адрес страницы где ставится сессия и считывается разные?

Comment: Не, даже на одной странице тестил... авторизуюсь- выводит...перезагружаю страницу, (сессия есть, но данные уже не выводятся)

Comment: Может дело в session_name(). Там есть нюанс — она возвращает имя старой сессии. Я точно не разбирался, но может дело в том, что функция перезаписывает сессию. Попробуйте без этой функции потестировать. Как бы на «дефолтном» варианте.

Comment: Проблема, но у меня даже такая запись выдает пустую сессию <?php

       /*  session_name("user");
         session_start();
          $_SESSION["user"] = 5555;*/
echo    $_SESSION["user"];
?> ход работы 1.дал создать сессию(она появилась)(и переменная вывелась на экран) 2. закоментил всё до echo и ничего не вывелось(хотя сессия осталась) это я сделал в отдельном файле

Comment: Ну session_start() нужно в любом случае выполнять.

Comment: Сделал и так, видать проблема не с сохранением... просмотрел temp... папку с сессиями, они создаются... но они тупо не принимают это $_SESSION["user"] = 5555; или подобные методы задания переменной

Answer (score 0):

Перенес в ответ, в комментариях код невозможно показать. Вот пример кода, на котором вы можете проверить работу сессии.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) $_SESSION['user'] = 'Вася';

echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

После выполнения этого кода, можете закомментировать строчку с «Васей» и проверить что выводит `$_SESSION['user']`.

Comment: Ваш код работает, спасибо...пойду думать...

Comment: Но есть проблема, сделал...но смотрите...  у меня выбор между запомнить и 1 сессией, проблема возникает запомнить        if ( $_POST['remember'] == '')
          {
            session_name("user");
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'Вася';
          } else {
            session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
            session_name("user");
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'Вася';
          }
чтоб после перезапуска браузера она работала, надо чтоб после перезапуска выполнялись эти строки  session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
 session_name("user"); а у меня они стоят в функции авторизации

Comment: Если вы хотите сохранять данные после перезапуска браузера, то нужны не сессии, а куки. Смотрите POST-опцию, если она есть и ставите куку на год. При авторизаци и смотрите наличие этой куки и если она есть, то проводите авторизацию по её сохраненным данным. Параметры  из session_set_cookie_params() работают только в пределах работы скрипта. То что вы используете  session_set_cookie_params и  session_name — это особые условия — нужно тестировать и проверять как оно работает на вашем сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Все действия с сессией имеют смысл только после запуска session_start().

Поставьте вызов этой функции в самое начало страницы.