# Как решить проблему с кнопкой запомнить?

Tags: php

Я запускаю сессию в глобальном файле индексе, который является единой точкой входа. Далее следует второй уровень индексных файлов, во втором авторизация и такой код при авторизации:

```
if ( $_POST['remember'] == '')
{
    session_name("user");
    $_SESSION['user'] = 'Вася';
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
    session_name("user");
    $_SESSION['user'] = 'Вася';
}
```

Проблема возникает в  моменте

```
session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
session_name("user");
```

их надо как и запуск сессии на всех страницах ставить, а у меня они активируются ток при допуске от файла авторизации. Тем самым  при перезапуске браузера сессия остается, но без имени и времени....а это уже другая сессия...значит и без переменной ...как решить

Comment: "_их надо как и запуск сессии на всех страницах ставить_". Уходите от стиля программирования с копипастом. Выделите одинаковые действия в отдельный файл, библиотеку и включайте в страницы include. И этот модуль должен собственно настроить переменные сессии, запустить ее и если ее нет вызывать логин. А вот причем тут перезапуск браузера я не понял, вы же время жизни куки задали, следовательно при перезапуске браузера кука останется (если время не вышло)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не происходит запись данных в сессию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842904/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e)